# Segmentation fault when using fprintf output __LINE__

Tags: c, printf

The code as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    fprintf(stderr, "%s \n", __LINE__);

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
# gcc b.c
# ./a.out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__LINE__` expands to an integer constant. Use `%d` to print it:

```
fprintf(stderr, "%d \n", __LINE__);
```

*§6.10.8.1  Mandatory macros (C11 draft)*

> __LINE__ The presumed line number (within the current source ﬁle) of the current source line (an integer constant).

---

If the `__LINE__` macro being overflowing `int` is a concern, then you can cast it to `uintmax_t` and print it. This is the safest way as `uintmax_t` is the largest integer type.

```
#include <stdint.h>

fprintf(stderr, "%ju \n", (uintmax_t)__LINE__);
```

Comment: This will be UB if a file has more than than 32767 lines and your platform has 16 bit `int`.

Comment: @Bathsheba On that logic, `long long` wouldn't work either. Typically, `int` is 32-bits on most platforms and if your source file has `4294967296` (`2^32 - 1`) lines then `__LINE__` macro is the least of your problems :)

Comment: Although this is a good answer (plus one), it is troubling that C is so lapse on the type for `__LINE__`. I still think that, on balance, using `(long)__LINE__` is the safest thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of your program is *undefined* since your format specifier is incorrect.

However, the C standard is irritatingly lapse on the *type* of `__LINE__`. It merely states it is a integral type. That means it could be an `int` or, if an `int` is not big enough (an `int` could have a maximum size of 32767), then it will be a `long`.

So to be really sure, I'd use `%ld` as the format specifier and write

`fprintf(stderr, "%ld \n", (long)__LINE__);`

For *really* big files, I conject it could be a `long long` type; then you'd 
need

`fprintf(stderr, "%lld \n", (long long)__LINE__);`

Comment: Where an `int` could be 16 bits wide?

Comment: Indeed: but you should allow for this for portability.

Answer (score 1):

Since `__LINE__` is an integer constant, you can't use it as a string. If you need a string, you'll have to tell the pre-processor to convert the number to a string:

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define STR(x) STRINGIFY(x)

fprintf(stderr, "%s \n", STR(__LINE__));
```

Answer (score 0):

`__LINE__` is actually in effect an Integer constant, and by trying to print it as a string, the system searches for things to print until the terminator, which an integer constant does not have, causing the process to go into memory its not supposed to. Result is ofcourse a segfault in that case.

Long story short, use `%d` as format specifier to print this.

Answer (score 0):

`__LINE__` needs at least `%d` format, because of is an integer constant.

A good tip: compile always with `-Wall` option. In your case you'll see:

```
b.c: In function ‘main’:
b.c:5:5: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     fprintf(stderr, "%s \n", __LINE__);
```